# Azure Created Image Without Generalizing

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

So I made the mistake of trying to capture an image of my VM without first running sysprep /generalize on it. Now I have a VM I can't start and an image I can't create a VM from.

Is there any way I can restore my original VM so I can create a valid image from it?

I saw this blog post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shwetanayak/captured-the-virtual-machine-didnt-intend-to-generalize-it-now-what that seems to imply that I can, but it's solution says to create a copy of a VHD using a snapshot. When I try to create the snapshot, nothing shows up in the Source Disk managed disks drop down.

Comment: I was able to restore my VM following the directions in that blog post. I was able to create a snapshot by selecting my disk in the portal and using the snapshot option there. I'm guessing if I had deleted the VM I tried to create an image from the disk would have showed up in the new snapshot portal.

Comment: Do you delete your original VM's vhd or managed disk?

Comment: After I was able to create a new VM from the disk snapshot I did delete the original VM and disk.

Comment: Updated link to blog post here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shwetanayak/captured-the-virtual-machine-didnt-intend-to-generalize-it-now-what