# Created image of Azure VM before generalizing and not able to start that VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

[Azure Created Image Without Generalizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950264/azure-created-image-without-generalizing)

I have same issue, which have mentioned in this question. In question given blog URL is also not working. Can anyone please help me, if you get any solution of this question?

Comment: Hello upeksha, may I know if you still face this issue?

Comment: Hi Nancy, Yes still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Could you describe what you have tried?  do you try the methods in my reply?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with your reply answer. But not able to change my VM status. And I want to change VM from generalize to running.

Comment: `Once VM is considered generalized and cannot be restarted. The process of generalizing a VM is not reversible.` If you need to keep the original VM functioning, you should create a copy of the VM and generalize its copy. BUt I think you have not copied it before it was generalized, so now you could create a new VM but use original OS disk . Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource)

Comment: Edit my reply to make it clear, do you have more concerns?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you could not change the status of old generalized VM to running. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource). Also, the link states that you could create a managed image from a  snapshot or a managed disk or a VHD in a storage account, then you could create a VM form the managed image.

> After you have run Sysprep on a VM, that VM is considered generalized
>   and cannot be restarted. The process of generalizing a VM is not
>   reversible. If you need to keep the original VM functioning, you
>   should create a copy of the VM and generalize its copy.

In this case, if you have no a copy for it, you could create a VM from original OS disk as the image, then you could login to the new Azure VM with the original credentials. Since VM use virtual hard disks (VHDs) to store their operating system (OS) and data. VHDs are also used for the images you can choose from to install an OS.

1. Make sure the disk state is **unattached**.
2. Click **create VM** to create a VM from this OS disk.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to [create a VM from a VHD by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal#create-a-vm-from-a-disk).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Create a snapshot out of the OS disk of the VM you are having trouble with.

**How to Create a Snapshot**

[Create a Snapshot (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/snapshot-copy-managed-disk)

**Step 2**: Create a new managed disk. Make sure that you select **Snapshot** from the **Source Type** drop-down and then select the newly created snapshot from the Snapshot Source drop-down. Click on the **Create** button.

**Step 3**: Go to the managed disk you created and click on the **Create VM** button which will start the VM and attach the the managed disk as an OS disk to the new VM. Complete the VM creation process.

And that's it!